# Can you "install" GLPK in Windows, and is it even possible to install PyGLPK in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, compilation, installation, glpk

Since [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635066/how-do-i-install-pyglpk-in-python-2-7-on-my-windows-machine) was met with dead silence, I've futilely tried more research and experimentation. I think it *should* be possible to install PyGLPK in Python 2.7 on Windows because I managed to get PyGLPK installed in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu, but I just cannot seem to do the same in Windows 7.

I am beginning to suspect that it has something to do with not "installing" GLPK properly on Windows, but I am at a bit of a loss for how to properly do that. The "official" way of doing it (according to [this](http://winglpk.sourceforge.net/)) is to "copy the DLLs to %SystemRoot%nsystem32 (e.g. c:\windows\system32)," but that is confusing because there are dll files with "dll" in the name, dll files without "dll" in the name, batch files with "dll" in the name, files that aren't classified into any particular type, and should I copy the dll's directly or put them inside what folder or subfolder? I tried just putting everything directly under C:/Windows/System32, but that didn't help me install PyGLPK.

Here is the full text of the error message I am getting after I try "python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32 install":

> running build
>
> running build_ext
>
> building 'glpk' extension
>
> c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Isrc -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src\glpk.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\glpk.o -m32
>
> In file included from src\glpk.c:21:
>
> src\lp.h:24:18: error: glpk.h: No such file or directory
>
> In file included from src\glpk.c:21:
>
> src\lp.h:32: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'glp_prob'
>
> src\lp.h:49: error: expected ')' before '*' token
>
> src\glpk.c: In function 'initglpk':
>
> src\glpk.c:52: error: 'GLP_MAJOR_VERSION' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> src\glpk.c:52: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>
> src\glpk.c:52: error: for each function it appears in.)
>
> src\glpk.c:52: error: 'GLP_MINOR_VERSION' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> src\glpk.c:53: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glp_version'
>
> src\glpk.c:53: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I would really like to be able to use this tool for my thesis project so this is very important to me. Thank you to anyone who has any clue about what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can download binaries from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencobra/files/python/cobra/extras/pyGLPK/) and just install like other applications on windows. I have done in this way but have not test yet.